# Flutter => showDialog / AlertDialog => No MaterialLocalizations found

Tags: flutter

just new to Flutter but very impressed.
I want to show a Dialog if a PushNotification arrives via Firebase "onMessage".

But every Time I get a Exception "No MaterialLocalizations found." if trying to show my Dialog.
For testing I added a RaisedButton to show this Alert, but same problem.
Perhaps somebody can help me. 
Thanks a lot!!!

Here is my whole code for the small app:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(Main());

class Main extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainState createState() => _MainState();
}

class _MainState extends State<Main> {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

  Widget _buildDialog(BuildContext context) {
    print("_buildDialog");
    return AlertDialog(
      content: Text("Item  has been updated"),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: const Text('CLOSE'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context, false);
          },
        ),
        FlatButton(
          child: const Text('SHOW'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context, true);
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _showPushDialog() {
    print("DIALOG");
    showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => _buildDialog(context),
    ).then((bool shouldNavigate) {
      if (shouldNavigate == true) {
        _navigateToPushDetail();
      }
    });
  }

  void _navigateToPushDetail() {
    print("TODO: Goto...");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        //_neverSatisfied();
        _showPushDialog();
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        _navigateToPushDetail();
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
        _navigateToPushDetail();
      },
    );

    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
      assert(token != null);
      print("Push Messaging token: $token");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: new Material(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Text('Hello World'),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print("pushed?");
                _showPushDialog();
              },
              child: Text("press me"),
            )
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Order to Fix the error, You need to Call Your `Main` class as a home parameter of `MaterialApp`as Like Below.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Main(),
    );
  }
}
```

& update your Build Method in `Main` Class as:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
      ),
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Text('Hello World'),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print("pushed?");
            _showPushDialog(context);
          },
          child: Text("press me"),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
```

Comment: But you didn't explain the reason... The reason for that is that the `context` parameter that you receive in your `Main` app is above the `MaterialApp` widget, and that is the context the dialog uses, and therefore any search for an `Localizations.localeOf(context)` will search starting from above the `MaterialApp`, which is the widget that sets localizations. Actually, another way to fix this is to put a `Builder` widget in between.

Answer (score 16):

#### Flutter 1.0, Dart 2.x

This solution works on both `StatelessWidget` widget and `StatefulWidget` widget.

On the top, in your declaration you can create a static `navKey`:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title; // sample var you want to pass to your widget
  static final navKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  const MyApp({Key navKey, this.title}) : super(key: navKey);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MyAppState();
}
```

On the layout part you should use the key:

```
return MaterialApp(
        navigatorKey:MyApp.navKey,
        title: widget.title,
        ...
```

So, when you need the current context for your dialog or other widget, in the state part you can do :

```
@override
  void initState() {
  final context = MyApp.navKey.currentState.overlay.context;
  showMyCustomDialog(context);
  ...
  super.initState();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**It's actually a lot simpler than the previous answers are trying to show it.** Try it like this:

1. First option. In the root widget you add `initialRoute` and `routes`:

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  initialRoute: '/',
  routes: <String, Widget Function(BuildContext)>{
    '/': (context) => const HomePage()
  },
);
```

2. Second option. In the root widget you wrap `Builder` widget:

```dart
return MaterialApp(
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) => const HomePage(),
      ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

check your `MaterialApp()` widget,
if you set `localizationsDelegates` ,may be you well get this problem.
it works when i delete those code.

```
              localizationsDelegates: [
                  DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
              ],
```

my codes.

```
MaterialApp(
              navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
              title: 'test',
              theme: ThemeData(
                  platform: TargetPlatform.iOS,
                  backgroundColor: Color(0xfff1f1f1),
                  accentColor: AppStyle.colorPrimary,
                  primaryColor: AppStyle.colorPrimary,
                  buttonColor: AppStyle.colorPrimary,
                  iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
                  textTheme: TextTheme(
                      title: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(title: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  primaryIconTheme: const IconThemeData.fallback().copyWith(
                      color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme().copyWith(brightness: Brightness.dark),
              ),
              home: LoginPage(),
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              onGenerateRoute: AppRouter.router.generator,
          )
```