# Creating an alert dialog

Tags: flutter

I try to open alert but there is an error, what is wrong?

> Unhandled Exception: No MaterialLocalizations found. MyApp widgets
>   require MaterialLocalizations to be provided by a Localizations widget
>   ancestor.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  void _getCsvDocunent(BuildContext ctx) async {
    if (ctx != null) _showAlert(ctx, 'Hello world');
  }

  Future _showAlert(BuildContext context, String message) async {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        child: new AlertDialog(
          title: new Text(message),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context), child: new Text('Ok'))
          ],
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Show alert'),
                onPressed: () => _getCsvDocunent(
                    context), // show alert from _getCsvDocunent
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54035175/flutter-showdialog-alertdialog-no-materiallocalizations-found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `context` you are passing while returning `showDialog` cannot locate the `MaterialLocalization` widget. As the error says `MyApp` widget requires `MaterialLocalization`, that means we need to return `MaterialApp` in `MyApp` class instead of, in the build method you provided. Sample working code below:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Test",
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  void _getCsvDocunent(BuildContext ctx) async {
    if (ctx != null) _showAlert(ctx, 'Hello world');
  }
```

Which shows the dialog as expected:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `FlatButton` with `Builder` widget.

```
Builder(
  builder: (context) {
    return FlatButton(
      child: Text('Show alert'),
      onPressed: () => _getCsvDocunent(context),
    );
  },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Include `builder:` in your `showDialog` widget.

Sample code for the material alert

```
Future<void> _materialAlertInit(BuildContext context) async {
  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return _materialAlert(context);
    },
  );
}

_materialAlert(BuildContext context) {
  return AlertDialog(
    title: Text('Material Alert'),
    content: Text('Android material designa alert'),
    actions: <Widget>[
      FlatButton(
        child: Text('Yes'),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
      FlatButton(
        child: Text('No'),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      )
    ],
    elevation: 24.0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  );
}
```

Comment: @A.Shukri check the repo for implementation https://github.com/dineshnagarajandev/Flutter-Basic/blob/master/lib/main.dart

Comment: If you have some free time , please help me on this link .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66541066/unhandled-exception-no-materiallocalizations-found-flutter?noredirect=1#comment117631467_66541066

Answer (score 0):

**Alert Dialog with two buttons**

```
confirmationPopup(BuildContext context1) {
  showDialog(
      context: context1,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Alert"),
          content: Text("Are you sure you want to logout?"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("No"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("Yes"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();

              },
            )
          ],
        );
      });
}
```